# Fetch JSON with Flutter and NULL safey

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

My JSON is updating over time, at start, I may have Null value, but like 15 minutes later, I may have something.  How can I  do my Class with null safety ? I have this error when I create the class.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PowerPlayInfo.fromJson function the parameter is of type Map<String, dynamic>.
Change the type to Map<String, dynamic>? (with the question mark) and it will be able to accept null values as well.
You can read more about null safety here https://flutter.dev/docs/null-safety